# Need to give page break in inner PdfPTable of iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext, pdfptable, page-break-inside

I am printing my html string in to pdf using iTextSharp.
I have nested table hierarchy. I need the Inner table should be break if its not fit in the current page and Start printing on new page.

I have putted the

```
KeepTogether = true;
SplitLate = false;
LockedWidth = true;
```

For all the tables that is for parent as well as all the child tables.

But in my case the Inner table is not breaking.

Here is the Image.
[image]

I am adding main parent table in document.add(parentTable).

I have checked that If I separate the child table from parent table and add in document directly, its breaking the page whenever require.

But for nested table its not breaking .

Can you please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, Any one have idea ? Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Please provide more than a couple of lines of code. Maybe a snippet that describes the different tables' creation?